# ATI Radeon Drivers works with which linux distribution and version?

Tags: linux, amd-catalyst

I have ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5850 graphics card. Almost every new linux distribution seems to have an issue with it, when i install the drivers. Working without utilizing the graphics card leaves me so unproductive. So i made a plan to use older versions of linux, any distribution suitable as a desktop distribution.

UPDATE: The kind of problems that i am facing are, 
1) After installing drivers the system boots and hangs,
2) There are unusual lines over the screen
3) After upgrade system doesn't start properly(hangs the usual old way)

The kind of answers i am looking for is, distribution X(the newer the version the better) doesn't have the above problem after installing drivers for ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5850 graphics card.

UPDATE: The new drivers released by AMD seems to fix all the issues, although they are still beta
Thanks

Comment: Try using some `fglrx` package from your distribution.

Comment: It just didn't work fine and when it did work, the system became unusable after some upgrades..., I can see a number of posts in various forums which do say there are many issues with catalyst drivers

Comment: Exactly what sort of problem are you seeing? Please update your question. Otherwise I cannot see what might an answer look like, a list of distribution/videocard/driver-version combinations?

Comment: You won't get answers here on Stack Overflow. Try asking on SuperUser.